# Javascript: Earliest moment to add event listener to document object

Tags: javascript, events, onload

I want to add a keydown event listener to the document object without JQuery.

In the listener I'm not accessing the DOM. The only thing I need from the DOM is the document object itself. I only want to disable pressing of certain key.

Is it safe to call it directly in the script (I mean when the script loads), or do I need to use onload callback (or maybe something else)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Interesting, I always guessed that `document` was available all the time, therefore you should be able to directly call the script, but it would be interesting to see an answer with a reference (Either confirming or denying this)

Comment: @julio.olvr It should always be "available", otherwise the below answer binding events to it wouldn't work. But I agree, a very specific reference would be nice for understanding/completeness sake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `document` object is always available wherever you place your script. No need to wait for `DOMContentLoaded` or anything; just add your listener whenever you like.

This is not true for elements within the document.

Answer (score 4):

You can just bind to the `DOMContentLoaded` event.  That is how jQuery does it.

Example:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    //Bind the key event here.
});
```

That doesn't work in IE.  So, for IE, you can do this:

```
document.attachEvent("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    //Bind the key event here.
});
```

Comment: hm well but if the document object is available in order to add "DOMContentLoaded" event, then I can add directly the keydown event. I dont need anything in the DOM besides the document.

Comment: The DOM is always loaded. The question is if I need to wait for that (and react in the callback), or if I can use the document object before loaded/ready/whatever is called. It seems the latest it's the case.

Answer (score 0):

```
   document.onload = function() {
        document.onkeydown = function() {
        // disable key

        };
    }
```

might work.

Comment: Why is onload necessary? I don't want to access the DOM in the listener.

Comment: Well, maybe it's not. Try it I guess.